# How to handle 2 event source using 2 separate thread in golang

Tags: go, design-patterns, responsive-design

This is a design-related question. I have a situation where my application receives events from 2 different sources it is registered with and the application should handle events from these 2 sources parallelly. My Application is already handling events from one source using the buffered channel (where events are queued up and processed one after another). Now I am in a situation where the application needs to handle the events from a different source and I cannot use the same channel here because the Application may have to handle events from these 2 sources parallelly. I am thinking of using another buffered channel to handle the events from the second event source. But I am concerned about the same resource being used to process 2 events parallelly. Even though we use channel we need to again apply sync while processing these events.

Could you please suggest me a better way, any patterns I can use, or a design to handle this situation?

This is the code I have now to handle event from one source

```
for event := range thisObj.channel {

    log.Printf("Found a new event '%s' to process at the state %s", event, thisObj.currentState)

    stateins := thisObj.statesMap[thisObj.currentState]
    // This is separate go routine. Hence acuire the lock before calling a state to process the event.
    thisObj.mu.Lock()
    stateins.ProcessState(event.EventType, event.EventData)
    thisObj.mu.Unlock()

}
```

Here thisObj.channel is being created at start up and the events are being added in a separate method. Currently this method is reading events from the channel and processing the events.

Comment: Show some code please

Comment: @AdoRen Update the code where I am reading the events from the channel and processing it

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [for select](https://go.dev/doc/effective_go#control_structures) pattern to read process your events from a single channel and process them in parallel:

```golang
var events *EventsChannel

for {
        select {
        case eventA = <-events:
        // handle A
        case eventB = <-events:
        // handle B
        default:
            // unknown type, error case

        }
    }
```